# Batch file that runs cmd as a different user and executes command lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cd

I need a `.bat` that will:

1. Open CMD as a different user, I use this line for it: 
   `runas /user:muc\axi8593 /savecred "cmd`(works just fine so far)
2. in the new CMD Window (running as different user) run command lines:
    `cd c:\temp\muc`
    `muc_exec.bat`

I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you could use [PsExec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) to run batch files under another account.

example:

```
psexec \\workstation64 -c test.bat -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
```

where test.bat could be `runas /user:muc\axi8593 /savecred "cmd`

Comment: I just get a CMD Window that runs in an endeles loop, Im new to scripting, can zou give me more percise info, thanks a lot!

Comment: you could make a batch file with the command you'd use, then you can call that batch script with psexec like in the example above

Answer (score 1):

To start another command prompt and run commands in it, you need to use either `/C` (if you want the prompt to close when done) or `/K` (if you want the prompt to remain open).

So you'd want something like:

```
runas /user:muc\axi8593 /savecred "cmd /C cd c:\temp\muc && muc_exec.bat"
```

The `&&` operator tells the prompt to run muc_exec.bat only if the `cd` operation worked. In this case, it would probably be simpler to just do `"cmd /C C:\temp\muc\muc_exec.bat"`, unless muc_exec can only be run from within its parent dir.